# parse json file from internet (with lots of quotes: " (not \")) with the Arduino JSON library

Tags: json, parsing, arduino, libraries, quote

i need to parse a json file from the internet with my arduino uno r3
(i cannot change the output / file), i have to use it as it is...

My json file i get from the internet looks like this: (example from https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson)

```
     char json[] = "{"sensor":"gps","time":1351824120,"data":[48.756080,2.302038]}";
```

The problem are the quotes "" inside the brackets,

If i change all quotes to \" everything works:

I provide an working Example from ArduinoJson library page:

```
    char json[] = "{\"sensor\":\"gps\",\"time\":1351824120,\"data\":[48.756080,2.302038]}";
    StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;

    JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);

    const char* sensor = root["sensor"];
    long time          = root["time"];
    double latitude    = root["data"][0];
    double longitude   = root["data"][1];
```

QUESTION:

How to replace the quotes, change them on the fly, or create the variable directly without the quotes, i need to parse the content afterwards.

Comment: On a valid json file you don't have the leading `"` it starts with `{`. Are you sure you get the leading `"` ?

Comment: no, for the arduino library i need the "{   }" ... But my problem are the quotes inside the brackets {"quotes" etc} they need to be \" like {\"quote\" etc}

Comment: Can you give a link to an example file ? You seems mixing how write the string in C and the content of the string. the string `foo"bar` is written `"foo\"bar"` but there is no `\\``  in the string and only one `"`

Comment: The parser i use and the correct code: https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson (under examples).

Comment: the json i request is here:  http://live.kvv.de/webapp/departures/bystop/de:8215:1619?maxInfos=4&key=377d840e54b59adbe53608ba1aad70e8

Comment: So there is no leading `"` what is your problem ?

Comment: How do you get the json ?

Comment: i get the json like this: first         client.println("GET http://live.kvv.de/webapp/departures/bystop/de:8215:1619?maxInfos=4&key=377d840e54b59adbe53608ba1aad70e8");      and then, for now i just output the json to serial like this:         if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);

Comment: the problem is:  i get a correct json file, but im not able to use any arduino Json library to parse it because all require the following format:  {\"text\":\"text\"} etc

Comment: Its NOT the leading " its all the Quotes inside!!!

Comment: Once again writing  `char *foo = "foo\"bar";` is the way to have the string `foor"bar`. The json you get has the correct format!. Try to print `"{\"text\":\"text\"} "` to see that there is no `\` inside your string. `\ ` is used to put a `"` inside a string.

Comment: Ok. But still it's not possible to solve my problem :  I need to request this  http://live.kvv.de/webapp/departures/bystop/de:8215:1619?maxInfos=4&key=377d840e54b59adbe53608ba1aad70e8%22  I cannot change the format but I need to parse it to get the desired output... How?

Comment: You need to get the content, put it into a `char *` without no change and call `jsonBuffer.parseObject()`. Can you post the code to get the json ?

Comment: client.println("GET http://live.kvv.de/webapp/departures/bystop/de:8215:1619?maxInfos=4&key=377d840e54b59adbe53608ba1aad70e8");          char c = client.read();         
    Serial.print(c);

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is how you get the data from the client.
You only read one char and not all the data.

Try something like this:
I don't have a wifi or ethernet shield I cannot test, so I don't know if your lib will skip the http headers.
Try to print data after the loop to check.

```
char data[1024];


void loop(void ) {
    int pos = 0;
    memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));
    /* here your code for the GET
    client.println("GET live.kvv.de/webapp/departures/bystop/…);
    */
    while (client.available() && pos < sizeof(data) - 1) {
        data[pos++] = client.read();
    }
    /* now you have all the data
       XXX: check if you need to skip http headers
       TODO: trigger an error is data is too small
    */
    jsonBuffer.parseObject(data);
```